# Делегирование. Массив. Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone

Добрый день! Проблема заключается в том, что я через делегирование передаю успешно все данные экземпляра weatherData класса WeatherData, ВСЕ, кроме массива :( Массив приходит пустой и я не могу понять в чем проблема. Память выделил.

Вот отрывок кода.

```
  WeatherData *weatherData = [[WeatherData alloc] init];

if (dicJSON != nil) {

    float currentTempC = [[[dicJSON objectForKey: KEY_CURRENT_OBSERVATION] objectForKey: KEY_CURRENT_TEMP_C] floatValue];
    int roundCurrentTempC = currentTempC;
    NSString *currentTempCString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", roundCurrentTempC];

    weatherData.city = [[[dicJSON objectForKey: KEY_CURRENT_OBSERVATION] objectForKey: KEY_DISPLAY_LOCATION] objectForKey: KEY_CITY];
    weatherData.country = [[[dicJSON objectForKey: KEY_CURRENT_OBSERVATION] objectForKey: KEY_DISPLAY_LOCATION] objectForKey: KEY_COUNTRY];
    weatherData.currentTempC = currentTempCString;
    weatherData.currentTempF = [[dicJSON objectForKey: KEY_CURRENT_OBSERVATION] objectForKey: KEY_CURRENT_TEMP_F];
    weatherData.weatherDescription = [[dicJSON objectForKey: KEY_CURRENT_OBSERVATION] objectForKey: KEY_WEATHER_DESCRIPTION];
    weatherData.realFeelTempC = [[dicJSON objectForKey: KEY_CURRENT_OBSERVATION] objectForKey: KEY_REALFEEL_TEMP_C];

    weatherData.humidity = [[dicJSON objectForKey: KEY_CURRENT_OBSERVATION] objectForKey: KEY_HUMIDITY];
    weatherData.windspeedkph = [[dicJSON objectForKey: KEY_CURRENT_OBSERVATION] objectForKey: KEY_WIND_KPH];
    weatherData.visibilityKm = [[dicJSON objectForKey: KEY_CURRENT_OBSERVATION] objectForKey: KEY_VISIBILITY_KM];
    weatherData.fallout = [[dicJSON objectForKey: KEY_CURRENT_OBSERVATION] objectForKey: KEY_FALLOUT];
    weatherData.iconCurrentWeather = [[dicJSON objectForKey: KEY_CURRENT_OBSERVATION] objectForKey: KEY_ICON];


    ////////

    if (hourlyDicJSON != nil) {

        WeatherData *weatherData = [[WeatherData alloc] init];

        NSArray *hourlyArr = [hourlyDicJSON objectForKey: @"hourly_forecast"];

        //        NSMutableArray *parsedHourlyArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        NSUInteger count = [hourlyArr count];
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            NSDictionary *hourDict = hourlyArr[i];
            NSMutableDictionary *hourParsedDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            NSString *hour = [[hourDict objectForKey: @"FCTTIME"] objectForKey: @"hour"];
            NSString *temp = [[hourDict objectForKey: @"temp"] objectForKey: @"metric"];
            NSString *icon = [hourDict objectForKey: @"icon"];

            [hourParsedDict setObject: hour forKey: @"hour"];
            [hourParsedDict setObject: temp forKey: @"temp"];
            [hourParsedDict setObject: icon forKey: @"icon"];

            [weatherData.parsedHourlyArr insertObject: hourParsedDict atIndex: i];
        }

        NSLog(@"PARSED HOURLY ARRAY\n\n\n%@", weatherData.parsedHourlyArr);
        NSLog(@"HOURLY COUNT ELEMENTS %lu", weatherData.parsedHourlyArr.count);
    }

    [_delegate weatherDownloaderCallback: weatherData];
```

На приходе юзаю так.

`NSLog(@"SetupWithActuallyDataFORECASTVIEW\n %lu", (unsigned long)data.parsedHourlyArr.count);
    NSLog(@"JEJEJE %@", data.currentTempC );`

currentTempC юзается отлично, а вот parsedHourlyArr.count равен нулю :( Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: В коде, который вы привели, вы не выделяете память для weatherData.parsedHourlyArr. weatherData.parsedHourlyArr == nil, поэтому weatherData.parsedHourlyArr insertObject: ничего не делает. Создайте weatherData.parsedHourlyArr = [NSArray mutableArray] перед циклом.

Comment: документация по `NSMutableArray` утверждает, что в функции `insertObject:atIndex:` индекс не должен превышать количество элементов в массиве, то есть в вашем случае он ничего не делает. Поедложу попробовать `addObject:` вместо него.